# How to split text into sentences when there is no space after full stop?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I have a text like

*'A gas well near Surabaya in East Java operated by Lapindo Brantas Inc. has spewed steaming mud since May last year, submerging villages, industries and fields.A gas well near Surabaya in East Java operated by PT Lapindo Brantas has spewed steaming mud since May last year, submerging villages, factories and fields.Last week, Indonesia's coordinating minister for social welfare, Aburizal Bakrie, whose family firm controls Lapindo Brantas, said the volcano was a "natural disaster" unrelated to the drilling activities.President Susilo Bambang Yudhoyono last month ordered Lapindo to pay 3.8 trillion rupiah (420.7 million dollars) in compensation and costs'*

I want to split it into sentences. NLTK or any standard regex which I find online fails.

Comment: sentences, as in a list? or you just want new lines inserted?

Comment: Anything is fine.

Comment: What is your grammar description for end of a sentence?  Perhaps a period (full stop) followed by a capital letter?

Comment: `\.\"?[A-Z]\w+` should match a word starting with a capital letter, maybe quoted, after a full stop.

Comment: Yeah. That sounds alright? Can you give me regex.

Comment: This ^^ is a regex. Search for it, split at the match start.

Comment: @9000 The regex you gave did not split after ``industries and fields``

Comment: You can't parse NLTK sentences with regular expressions. It's not possible.

Comment: @RaghuramVadapalli, ah, yes, if requires a word at least  characters long, to avoid splitting at initials before names like 'H.P.Lovecraft'; probably the word "A" with a space after it should be special-cased. `\.\"?(?:[A-Z]\w+)|(?:A )` or something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex positive lookahead to add spaces to the end of sentences and then pass it to the tool of your choice. This adds a space to periods that don't already have one, but skips non-alphanumerics like commas. By sticking to character classes instead of, say, `A-Z`, this works for any language.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.(?=[^ \W\d])', '. ', 'Foo bar.Baz Inc., foobar. 1.1, and abc._')
'Foo bar. Baz Inc., foobar. 1.1, and abc. _'
```

You can catch some urls by adding another lookahead searching for slashes

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.(?=[^ \W\d])(?=[^\w*]/)', '. ', 'Foo bar.Baz Inc., foobar. 1.1, and abc._ http://www.example.com/whatever')
'Foo bar.Baz Inc., foobar. 1.1, and abc._ http://www.example.com/whatever'
```

Comment: Not quite... I tested and it added a space in 420.7. I'll update.

Comment: This will split up URLs in the text. It's not an easy problem... NLTK has a ["casual" tokenizer module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.casual) which is more robust towards non-standard spelling, but I'm afraid it only covers word toknenisation, not sentence splitting.

Comment: @lenz - interesting. I added another lookahead to catch some urls but If NLTK cleans this up, that's the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex to capture the dots that are followed by new sentences

`(\.)(?:[A-Z])`
you can  pass it to re.sub with r'\1\n' as a replacement

`parsed_text = re.sub(r'(\.)(?:[A-Z])',r'\1\n',your_text)`

you can also just split it into a list of sentences (but you lose the dots at the end)

```
 sentence_list = re.split(r'\.(?=[A-Z])',your_text)
```

Comment: This replaces first letter after full stop with new line.

Comment: my bad, i missed the non capturing group. its fixed now.

Comment: It still does not work. Still replaces first letter.